# Is there any way to send/insert value to hosted database using python script?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, url

I want to make a website and there will be a google map page on that website that will show location according to the long ,lat that will receive from a IoT device and I also want to store all the long,lat in data base so tell me they way by which I can send long,lat data to hosted data base from the device using python script.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: till now I have done only server side part I am manually Entering the long,lat in table and showing it on to map now I want to send send long lat from raspberrypi to server and how should I do using python ??